# Refactor part of a program to a loop to make it smaller

Tags: loops, assembly, mips

I wrote some code but it is too long. I thought maybe I could make my program a bit smaller by putting this part in loop. I tried by changing `0` to some register such as `$f9` and increment it, but it didn't work.

Anybody have some idea how I can do it?

```
windfact:   .float 1.201, 1.036, 2.320, 5.026, 6.321, 1.0215
newLine:    .asciiz "\n"

la  $t0, windfact           # put address of list into $a1
l.s $f12, 0($t0) 
li  $v0, 2           
syscall                     # This will print 1.192173
li       $v0, 4                 # system call code for print string
la       $a0, newLine           # load addr of newLine in $a0
syscall

l.s $f12, 4($t0) 
li  $v0, 2           
syscall                     
li       $v0, 4                 
la       $a0, newLine           
syscall

l.s $f12, 8($t0) 
li  $v0, 2           
syscall                     
li       $v0, 4                 
la       $a0, newLine           
syscall

l.s $f12, 12($t0) 
li  $v0, 2           
syscall                     
li       $v0, 4                 
la       $a0, newLine           
syscall

l.s $f12, 16($t0) 
li  $v0, 2           
syscall                     
li       $v0, 4                 
la       $a0, newLine           
syscall

l.s $f12, 20($t0) 
li  $v0, 2           
syscall                     
li       $v0, 4                 
la       $a0, newLine           
syscall
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to iterate over your array, loading each successive value into `$f12`.  One way to do that is to increment a pointer into the array, rather than incrementing an index.

In C, it's like doing

```
float *array_end = array+size;   // keep this in a register to compare against
for(float *p = array ; p < array_end ; p++ )
    do_stuff(*p);
```

As opposed to

```
for(int i=0 ; i < size ; i++ )
    do_stuff(array[i]);
```

---

In the ABI you're using, does the `syscall` instruction preserve its input registers?  If so, you only need to set `$f12` and `$a0` once each, whether you fully unroll (like now) or not.

If not, you'll have to spill your loop pointer/counter to memory across syscalls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know how to do it in java but I am not able to write the same for mips. like you said: "As opposed to

for(int i=0 ; i < size ; i++ )
    do_stuff(array[i]);" 
Can you please guide me how to write this code in MIPS?

Comment: @jai: get a pointer to the array into a register, then increment it by 4 inside the loop.  Java doesn't have pointers, which is why I explained it using C.  The code fragment you quoted is the one that *doesn't* translate as directly into ASM.